# Wordpress custom excerpt character based - tweak

Tags: php, wordpress

after some research and writing customized excerpt function I was able to solve my problem partially. What I wanted to achive while writing chracter based excerpt function was to end every excerpt in the same place... However it's still can't make it. Can you please take a look at the function, maybe you will have and idea what could be improved.

[image: My aim was to create excerpt always same lenght despite the content]

```
function get_excerpt(){
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 480);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strrpos($excerpt, ' ')); // End with full word
$excerpt = $excerpt.'...';
return $excerpt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cześć Mkb! You must choose between 'end in same place' or 'end with full word' :P However try it:

```
function get_excerpt(){
    $excerpt = get_the_content();
    $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
    $endNearPos = 480;

    $temp1 = strrpos ( substr($excerpt, 0, $endNearPos) , ' ' );
    $temp2 = strpos ( $excerpt , ' ', $endNearPos );

    if( abs($endNearPos - $temp1) > abs($endNearPos - $temp2) ){
        return substr($excerpt, 0, $temp2).'...';
    } else {
        return substr($excerpt, 0, $temp1).'...';
    }
}
```

Still not in same place but closer.

Comment: Dzięki! It's close enough for now, I will let you know if it still works well with real data.